# NameError says variable is not defined, but only in some places

Tags: python, nameerror, scoping

I am trying to implement a keep-alive that sends some data every 30 seconds to keep a telnet connection open.

My code calls `reinitScore` every second.  This function will sometimes call `calculateWinner`, which sends the data through telnet via `stelnet.send(data)`.

The problem is, when I call `stelnet.send(data)` inside any function, it raises a `NameError: global name 'stelnet' is not defined`.

My questions is: why would `stelnet.send(data)` work in one place, and not another?

Here is the part of my code that concerns telnet transfer and function calling:

```
import socket, select, string, sys
import string
import threading

leftKeyCounter = 0
rightKeyCounter = 0
frontKeyCounter = 0
backKeyCounter = 0

# function called by reinitScore
def calculateWinner(d):
    scores = {}
    high_score = 0
    for key, value in d.items():
        try:
            scores[value].append(key)
        except KeyError:
            scores[value] = [key]
        if value > high_score:
            high_score = value
    results = scores[high_score]
    if len(results) == 1:
        print results[0]
        stelnet.send(results[0])
        return results[0]
    else:
        print 'TIE'
        return 'TIE', results

#called once and repeat itselfs every second
def reinitScore():
    threading.Timer(1, reinitScore).start()
    #globaling for changing the content
    global leftKeyCounter
    global rightKeyCounter
    global frontKeyCounter
    global backKeyCounter
    values = {'left' : leftKeyCounter, 'right' : rightKeyCounter, 'front' : frontKeyCounter, 'back' : backKeyCounter}
    if (leftKeyCounter != 0 or rightKeyCounter != 0 or frontKeyCounter != 0 or backKeyCounter != 0):
        calculateWinner(values)
        leftKeyCounter = 0
        rightKeyCounter = 0
        frontKeyCounter = 0
        backKeyCounter = 0
        print "back to 0"

reinitScore()
if __name__ == "__main__":

    if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :


    print 'Usage : python telnet.py hostname port'
    sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2]) 
    stelnet = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    stelnet.settimeout(2)

    # connect to remote host
    try :
        stelnet.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print 'Unable to connect'
        sys.exit()

    print 'Connected to remote host'

    while True:
       // ... Some code that has nothing to do with telnet 

    while 1:
       socket_list = [sys.stdin, stelnet]

        read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

        for sock in read_sockets:
            if sock == stelnet:
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if not data :
                    print 'Connection closed'
                    sys.exit()
                else :
                    sys.stdout.write(data)

            else :
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()
                stelnet.send(msg)
```

I tried to declare `stelnet` as a `global` variable at many places, but it doesn't change anything --- I always get the "not defined" `NameError`.

Comment: This code as it is works, but when I try to put `stelnet.send(data)` in reinitscore for example, it returns the not defined error

Comment: What do you mean by "in the last function"... `reinitScore`, the last function `def` in the code you've posted, or the last _call_ to a function that uses `stelnet` (wherever that is)?  Something else?  And, what makes you think it's working?  I don't see how _any_ use of the name `stelnet` could work.

Comment: How sure are you that the `while True:` loop "has nothing to do with telnet"?  If `stelnet` is defined in that loop, it would become the module-level variable you're looking for... but not until that line gets executed.  (This kind of confusion is why you should keep your code _out_ of the module's namespace as much as possible.)

Comment: I added the place where stelnet is defined, I forgot that yesterday ( even it's the main part of my code... ) sorry for that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your updated code...  The error message is *still* correct, because although you have defined `stelnet` at the module level, you've defined it too late.  It's definition occurs *after* its use in the `calculateWinner` function.

Stripping your code down to a ridiculously minimal example, you are doing something like this:

```python2
def calculateWinner():
    # A leap of faith...  There is no `stelnet` defined
    # in this function.
    stelnet.send(results[0])

def reinitScore():
    # Indirectly depends on `stelnet` too.
    calculateWinner()

# But we haven't defined `stelnet` yet...
reinitScore() # Kaboom!

# These lines will never run, because the NameError has
# already happened.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    stelnet = ...  # Too late.
```

`calculateWinner` depends on a name that *does not exist* when the function is compiled.  Whether it works or crashes will depend on whether some other code has defined `stelnet` 1) where `calculateWinner` can get at it, and 2) before `calculateWinner` is executed.

**Suggestions**

Functions that depend on global mutable state are hard to follow, let alone code correctly.  It's not easy to tell what depends on which variables, or what's modifying them, or when.  Also, coming up with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is more trouble than it should be, because functions that appear independent might not be.

Stuff as much of your module-level code as you can into a `main` function, and call it (and nothing else) from the body of `if __name__ == '__main__':` (since even *that* is actually at module level).

Consider something like this:

```python2
def reinit_score(output_socket, shared_scores):
    # Ensuring safe concurrent access to the `shared_scores`
    # dictionary is left as an exercise for the reader.
    winner = ...  # Determined from `shared_scores`.
    output_socket.send(winner)
    for key in shared_scores:
        shared_scores[key] = 0
    threading.Timer(
      interval=1,
      function=reinit_score,
      args=[output_socket, shared_scores],
      ).start()

def main():
    output_socket = ...  # This was `stelnet`.
    shared_scores = {...}  # A dictionary with 4 keys: L/R/U/D.
    reinit_score(output_socket, shared_scores)
    while True:
        play_game(shared_scores)
        # `play_game` mutates the `shared_scores` dictionary...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

These functions are still connected by the shared dictionary that they pass around, but only functions that are explicitly passed that dictionary can change its contents.

Comment: Damn I was so tired yesterday I didn't even notice that the most important part was missing, I added the place where I define stelnet,  could you have a look again ? really sorry.
I will definitely take a look at re-coding properly this whole code, thanks for the advices !

Comment: No, I still got the same problem even when re-writing my code in a different way. I got it working now by calling an independant function on the side, once, which repeats itself every 30 secs with threading

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are not passing `stelnet` to your function.

Comment: I can use stelnet in the calculateWinner function, and as far as I know, it doesn't seem that I am passing it to this function either ... That's the real question

Comment: @ThaoD5:  What makes you think `calculateWinner` works... or even runs?  I see no evidence of this, at least not with the code you've shown us so far.  (Try putting a `print` command as the first line of `calculateWinner` and see if that string ever gets printed.  Mine doesn't.)

Comment: CalculateWinner is a function thrown only if one of the 4 variables (left right back front key counter ) != 0, in my complete code, with the incrementation of those var, the calculateWinner funtion is called and then I am able to send via stelnet.send() some data.